# How to know which IPv6 interface will be chosen by the router?

Tags: ipv6, network, interface

I would like to know how does the kernel decide through which interface it sends data to some IPv6 address, how is the calculation done based on the routing table information: `destination`, `gateway` and `netmask`?

Comment: In a router, the route selection works the same way for IPv6 as it does for IPv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [RFC 6724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724). From the abstract of that specification:

> This document describes two algorithms, one for source address selection and one for destination address selection.  The algorithms specify default behavior for all Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) implementations.  They do not override choices made by applications or upper-layer protocols, nor do they preclude the development of more advanced mechanisms for address selection.  The two algorithms share a common context, including an optional mechanism for allowing administrators to provide policy that can override the default behavior.  In dual-stack implementations, the destination address selection algorithm can consider both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses -- depending on the available source addresses, the algorithm might prefer IPv6 addresses over IPv4 addresses, or vice versa.

It's quite a extensive algorithm, so I won't try to replicate its contents here. The link provided above is very stable and will not disappear :)  Feel free to ask questions in the comments and I'll try to clarify the answer if something is not clear!